# What will happen when Metal is a supported render device?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu

Currently, render devices include of none (CPU), OptiX (NVIDIA RTX), CUDA (NVIDIA), and OpenCL (AMD/Intel Iris/Iris Xe). when Apple Metal is officially released (blender announced partnership), will it show up as a render device to use?

Answer (score 1):

One thing that's been made clear by watching the Blender youtube channel livestreams is that it's heavily dependent on the level of support and assistance offered by the company.

For example, cycles rendering on nvidia gpus is almost always not a problem because nvidia has people on *their* payroll who make sure that's the case.

Here's the [devtalk thread](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/is-there-interest-in-supporting-a-metal-version-of-cycles-for-macos/4475/446), created years ago and active as of the past few hours. ;)